# NPM search shows package with same versions but different dates

Tags: node.js, npm

I've got a doubt about the command `npm search helpers` output.

```
npm WARN search fast search endpoint errored. Using old search.
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
helpers                                          |                 | 2018-08-27 | 1.9.6    |         
helpers                                          |                 | 2018-08-28 | 1.9.6    | 
helpers                                          |                 | 2018-08-28 | 1.9.6    | 
helpers                                          |                 | 2018-08-28 | 1.9.6    |
```

As you can see, the same package appairs three times with the same version but different dates. The package was published yesterday s version `1.9.6` and `unpublished`/published` today with the same version.
I this a normal behavior? I was expecting that one entry for each package version.

Comment: please attach full command npm search

Comment: HI @аlexdykyі. I amended the question :)

Answer (score 0):

`NPM` does'n have isuues with search or I can't reproduse your issue
try to update your npm with command `npm i -g npm` or `sudo npm i -g npm`

My investigation:

`$ npm -v`

`> 5.6.0`

`$ npm search helpers`

date `28/08/2018`
search result:

```
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
helpers                   | helper functions…    | =fshost         | 2013-07-23 | 0.0.6    |
babel-helpers             | Collection of…       | =existentialism… | 2017-04-07 | 6.24.1   |
@babel/helpers            | Collection of…       | =danez…         | 2018-08-27 | 7.0.0    |
underscore                | JavaScript's…        | =jashkenas…     | 2018-05-31 | 1.9.1    | util functional server client browser
@turf/helpers             | turf helpers module  | =rowanwins…     | 2018-05-20 | 6.1.4    | geo point turf geojson
dom-helpers               | tiny modular DOM…    | =monastic.panic | 2017-12-20 | 3.3.1    | dom-helpers react-component dom api cross-browser style event height width dom-helpers class classlist css
babel-plugin-external-hel | This plugin…         | =existentialism… | 2017-01-20 | 6.22.0   | babel-plugin
pers                      |                      |                 |            |          |
@babel/helper-plugin-util | General utilities…   | =danez…         | 2018-08-27 | 7.0.0    |
s                         |                      |                 |            |          |
postcss-message-helpers   | PostCSS helpers to…  | =jonathantneal… | 2015-01-26 | 2.0.0    | css postcss postcss-plugins messages error warning
babel-helper-function-nam | Helper function to…  | =existentialism… | 2017-04-07 | 6.24.1   |
e                         |                      |                 |            |          |
babel-helper-hoist-variab | Helper function to…  | =existentialism… | 2017-04-07 | 6.24.1   |
les                       |                      |                 |            |          |
babel-helper-define-map   | Helper function to…  | =existentialism… | 2017-08-16 | 6.26.0   |
babel-helper-regex        | Helper function to…  | =existentialism… | 2017-08-16 | 6.26.0   |
babel-plugin-transform-ru | Externalise…         | =existentialism… | 2017-02-13 | 6.23.0   | babel-plugin
ntime                     |                      |                 |            |          |
babel-helper-optimise-cal | Helper function to…  | =jmm…           | 2017-04-07 | 6.24.1   |
l-expression              |                      |                 |            |          |
@babel/helper-function-na | Helper function to…  | =danez…         | 2018-08-27 | 7.0.0    |
me                        |                      |                 |            |          |
babel-helper-get-function | Helper function to…  | =existentialism… | 2017-04-07 | 6.24.1   |
-arity                    |                      |                 |            |          |
enzyme                    | JavaScript Testing…  | =airbnb…        | 2018-08-25 | 3.5.0    | javascript shallow rendering shallowRender test reactjs react flux testing test utils assertion helpers tdd mocha
@babel/plugin-external-he | This plugin…         | =danez…         | 2018-08-27 | 7.0.0    | babel-plugin
lpers                     |                      |                 |            |          |
babel-helper-call-delegat | Helper function to…  | =existentialism… | 2017-04-07 | 6.24.1   |
e                         |                      |                 |            |          |
```

Comment: Helpers is a private repository on our own registry.

Comment: in next versions of your module, please create new git tags

Comment: Probably you don't get the point. git tags are nothing to do with it. If you try to publish the same module twice (i mean with the same version) the registry won't accept the second request. My question wasn't like how can I  publish 2 different version but more like why if the registry rejects the publish request I can see the same package version whit different dates?

Comment: @GiorgioCerruti , sorry but I don't know answer to your question, Try to add more details, and maybe someone can help you, also you can create issue in github on npm repository

Comment: No problems at all. Thank you for the help anyway :)